# Check if an object property changes its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, angularjs, node-webkit

I have two applications (one in C++, the other one in node-webkit) that communicate via OSC. When I press `+` a value will increment and when I press `-` that value will decrement. The output is sent to the node-webkit instance and then handles the message using:

```
$scope.$on('FooBar', function (event, obj) {
//stuff happens here
};
```

In this case, `obj` has one property, `foobar`, a positive integer, that goes up and down everytime I press the keys.
Thing is I need to change the corresponding local value of FooBar. I tried using:

```
 var aux = obj.foobar;
 if (aux < obj.foobar) {
       FooBarManager.raiseFooBar();
 } else {
       if (aux > obj.foobar) {
           FooBarManager.lowerFooBar();
   }
 }
```

but I can't get the logic working. Nothing happens since `aux` will always be equal to the property of `obj` when a key is pressed and the value is changed.

Comment: why are you doing this: `var aux = obj.foobar;` ? it doesn't make any sense if you do `>` and `<` checks afterwards and there is not enough code for me to tell what you should change...

Comment: I wanted to use some other variable that would save the old value, but wasn't able to do it and I asked it here

Comment: can you just show more of the js code. because from what you posted i can't see what you are trying to do.

Comment: I thought my question is straightforward and I don't understand the downvote reason. I want to use `raiseFooBar()` when `obj.foobar` is incremented from the outside and `lowerFooBar()` when `obj.foobar` is decremented. There is no other JS relevant code since my problem is the logic.

Supposing `obj.foobar` is 0, when I press `+` on the C++ side, it will change to 1. This change should consequently call `raiseFooBar()`. If I want to change it back to 0, I will press `-` on the C++ side and the JS should call `lowerFooBar()`. Please help me understand why is this question is not well written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work then?

```
var previousFooBar = 0; // whatever your default is
$scope.$on('FooBar', function (event, obj) {
 if (obj.foobar > previousFooBar) {
      FooBarManager.raiseFooBar();
 } else if (obj.foobar < previousFooBar) {
      FooBarManager.lowerFooBar();
 }
 previousFooBar = obj.foobar;
});
```